# Is using Pattern/Matcher more efficient than looping through a string and looking for characters?

Tags: java, regex, performance, iteration

I am working on a project that will look through a java file for a particular method, and output the lines that method occupies to a file. I am already using a Pattern and Matcher to find the method, but then I iterate through characters in a line to find matching curly braces.

My question is, would it be more efficient to use another Pattern/Matcher to find curly brace pairs?

Here is the method that finds the line range for the method, if it helps:

```
        String line;
        int currentLineNumber = 0;

        int methodStart = 0;
        int methodEnd = 0;

        int braceCount = 0;

        Matcher matcher;

        while ((line = lineReader.readLine()) != null) { // Must set line's value here because readLine() increments line number

            currentLineNumber = lineReader.getLineNumber();
            matcher = p.matcher(line); // initialize matcher with Pattern

            if (matcher.find()) { // if the line has a regex hit, store the line number as currentLine
                methodStart = currentLineNumber;
            }

            if (currentLineNumber >= methodStart && methodStart != 0) { // make sure that we've found the method
                for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) { // iterates through characters in the line
                    /*
                     * Start with a braceCount of 0. When you find a starting brace, increment.
                     * When you find an ending brace, decrement. When braceCount reaches 0 again,
                     * you will know that you have reached the end of the method.
                     * 
                     * Could possibly reduce complexity/increase efficiency by using set of patterns/matchers
                     * to find braces. 
                     */
                    if (line.charAt(i) == '{') 
                        braceCount++;

                    if (line.charAt(i) == '}') {
                        braceCount--;
                        if (braceCount == 0) {
                            methodEnd = currentLineNumber;
                            return new int[] { methodStart, methodEnd };
                        }
                    }

                }

            }

        }
```

Comment: it depends......

Comment: For complex patterns, probably.  For very simple character searches, almost certainly not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your particular case probably not.

You scan a Java `String` sequentially once. That is faster than building a `Matcher` and then using it to do the same. A `Matcher` is going to have to scan the `String` at least once, too, there is no magic in it.

In any case, always use a *profiler* (e.g. [VisualVM](https://visualvm.github.io/)) before going into performance-related optimizations.

---

A potentially much bigger problem is parsing Java with regex in the first place. Such a solution is inevitably fragile (for example, it is possible to write a Java method on a single line, there can be nested classes, generics, etc.).

There are many [Java parsers](http://javaparser.org/) around that can do the job in a much more robust way.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even consider that case. I will be looking into using a java parser instead, but out of curiosity, would a java parser be more efficient (not that efficiency matters too much for this case) or would it just offer, as you said, a more robust solution?

Comment: A parser will probably be a bit slower than a simple regex, but you get a lot of robustness in return. Profile to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly, yes

**Why**

1) You're already doing a regex line-by-line.  So the regex is already scanning the whole file, just piece by piece.

2) Remember, strings are Immutable in Java, so

```
while ((line = lineReader.readLine()) != null)
```

creates a new string object per-line.  Also consider that [readline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netframework-4.7.2), doesn't load in the whole file, then hand it to you a line at a time.  You'd probably see some speed enhancement reading the file in one go then parsing it line-by-line even without adding a regex.

NOTE: It may be infeasible to read in the whole file.  If so, ignore above.

Comment: The question is not about C#.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're getting at. Although I am using Java and not C#, it still holds true that Strings are immutable, so this is still good information.

Comment: Sorry - Java strings are also immutable